# VB.NET and SQL: how to update ListView / DatagridView from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a listview / datagrid on my vb form which is derived from the SQL Server database at form load. There are several users in my program

Now, whenever data is updated in certain tables (e.g. insert, update, delete), I want my listview / datagrid to be updated.

For example:

- User1 and User2: gets data into the listview / datagrid from SQL Server database at form load event
- User2: inserts data into a table in the SQL Server database
- User1: his listview / datagrid should be updated from the SQL Server database without clicking a button or any event inside the form. The server itself should update the listview / datagrid for User1

Purpose: I want to avoid frequent SQL queries (e.g. click refresh every time to update the listview / datagrid).

This method will boost speed in the user side without querying data from SQL Server database every time.

I am new to StackOverflow. Please consider. Thanks

Comment: Its not possible - how do you think it would work? SQL Server does now have any push mechanism... somewhere alone the way you need to check whether anything has changed and reload.

Comment: Too bad. I am expecting this kind of feature :(

Comment: One example of this is a Live Chat program. You don't want to click Refresh anytime in order to get latest messages right? Imagine, Facebook messenger wont give you messages if you don't click the Refresh button.

Comment: Facebook messenger has a specially written push service, and for that to work, messenger itself has to have a comms channel permanently open, waiting for a notification. So both ends needs support for such a feature, your front end, and the backend. Its a massive topic I suggest doing some research. All that aside, somewhere in the system is something either checking for changes, or events are being generated on changed.

Comment: I imagine you could achieve the desired effect by making use of SQL triggers to post a notification and/or advise the data changes to an object that you monitor in your program. However the server is not going to directly update your ListView/Datagrid. You would need to adapt your program to recognize the notifications. It would mean though that you don't need to run queries unless there has been a change.

Comment: You can look into the `SqlDependency` class, but it should only be used when the number of listeners is small. If you have a large number of clients then you could create a single application use `SqlDependency` and then have all your clients connect to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers sirs. I realize this is a quite topic. one simple solution is using a timer that constantly checks the sql server for updates; but that is another query that costs resources and performance :(

Comment: If you're doing this to allow users to work effectively with updating data concurrently, then you need to know that to a big degree the problem is already solved - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/handle-a-concurrency-exception?view=vs-2019 - If you're asking because you have to have all users have the most up to date data as soon as possible because they read it and make decisions on it (stock market prices for example) then you implement something yourself. Consider having your apps call a webservice,webservice updates DB and sends updated info to clients by SignalR